# What are hot spots on human body?

Tags: human-biology

Recently I have just discovered that a certain amount of the mobile phone frequency can be absorbed by human tissues.

For example, this is the SAR info of iPhone 4s:

```
Head: 1.180 W/kg 1 g
Body: 0.491 W/kg 1g
Hotspot: 0.491 W/kg 1 g
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone_4S

so hotspot means a hot spot on human body right?

Then question is:

What are hot spots on human body?

Comment: "Hot spot" does not refer to anything on the human body, but   testing while using the phone's "Personal hot spot" feature: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4517 See also the documents on "RF exposure info" at https://apps.fcc.gov/oetcf/eas/reports/ViewExhibitReport.cfm?mode=Exhibits&RequestTimeout=500&calledFromFrame=N&application_id=134990&fcc_id=%27BCG-E2430A%27

Comment: I think hotspot in that context means the highest exposure amount as this document shows (https://apps.fcc.gov/eas/GetApplicationAttachment.html?id=1544448), which comes from the reference the above wiki page provided.

Comment: @ Bez, i don't think so, hotspot mean "if iPhone works as a WiFi hotspot" & the Wi-Fi hotspot can generate WiFi electromagnetic radiation). I opened a WiFi last time & I suddenly feel a litle bit of uncomfortable when sitting next to it so i have to turn it off. (http://www.radiationtalk.com/info/wifi_radiation.php)

Comment: The author has listed the Specific absorption rate of radio frequencies and asked about hot spots which is not something associated with the human body and is a mobile phone technology (to my knowledge). The question is just wrong and the author has not made relevant efforts to understand the topic before placing the question.

Comment: I vote to keep open. The question is reasonable and easily answerable:"Hot spots" in this context does not refer to anything on the body).